# Git commit and push is adding a line break at the end

Tags: github

I need your wise help in understanding why when I commit and push something to Git, both my Terminal and GitHub CLI, it adds a `\n` at the end of the file.

This messes up things because it's a token that is being passed, and adding a line breaks things.

When I commit and push it from GoLand (IDE), this doesn't happen.

Any clues why?

Answer (score 0):

Check first the value of (in command-line, outside of your IDE)

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git config core.autocrlf
```

I recommend setting it to `false`, making sure that Git is not changing anything on checkout or commit.

And in Goland, activate the option "[Warn if CRLF line separators are about to be committed](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/settings-version-control-git.html#16d73d0a)".
That way, you will be notified if the same would ever occur in the IDE.